# How do you export annotations from an EPUB file done in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: microsoft-edge, epub

For me, the best thing about Edge was that It allowed you to **open EPUB files** as you shall open PDFs in Chrome *as well as* **add your own Annotations** (notes, underlines, comments, highlights, etc )*, Unlike* Chrome.

So, I have over a 1000 EPUB files which have my annotations.
Can I get a Large scale (Heck! any scale if possible) method by which I can export all my Bookmarks, Annotations of each and every book? (Preferably in an organised manner)